# What rescaling actually does in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, layer

I come across this layer `tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling`

I am making an image classification model but I have no idea what [their description](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/Rescaling) means.

It mentioned "To rescale an input in the [0, 255] range to be in the [0, 1] range"

Does it mean this layer turns my image into black and white?

How is this layer going to help my training?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No what it means is normally the pixel values in an image take on a range of values between 0 and 255. When you rescale the image the range of pixel values is changed. Most commonly pixel values are rescaled to a range from 0 to 1. Effectively it is taking each pixel value and dividing it by 255. This is the typical rescaling range used to preprocess images before they are used as input to a neural network, Some classic models like those present in Keras applications used in transfer learning were trained with pixel values in the range +1 to -1 and specify you use their associated preprocessing function to scale the images. You can accomplish the same thing by defining the rescale value as 1/127.5-1. Rescaling has nothing to do with changing images from RGB to grayscale.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what is the effect to the model if the input value is divided, will the accuracy decrease? What's the difference between use and not using it ? What's the motivation behind this function? For example, layers. rotation is quite straightforward, it rotate the image and creat variation , what about this one ?

Comment: no it does NOT impact accuracy in a negative way. Scaling helps the model perform better especially is you have multiple features with widely different means and standard deviations..

Comment: If your model expects a certain scale because it was trained with that scale in its inputs, then you must rescale to that scale, otherwise the outputs from the model on your inputs will be more or less meaningless.